# @media queries : getting an error in W3C CSS Validation Service

Tags: css, xhtml, media, w3c-validation, media-queries

I tried to fix the width of wrapper div using @media queries according to different screen size

**where i wrote these lines of code**

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px) {
 #wrapper {
 width:625px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
}
 @media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:2047px) {
 #wrapper {
 width:865px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-left: 50px;
 width: 927px;
}
}
```

**when i checked my file in W3C CSS Validation Service i got these lines of error**

```
Value Error : min-width Property min-width doesn't exist for media screen : 768px 768px
Value Error : max-width Property max-width doesn't exist for media screen : 1023px 1023px
Value Error : min-width Property min-width doesn't exist for media screen : 1024px 1024px
Value Error : max-width Property max-width doesn't exist for media screen : 2047px 2047px
```

what is the reason behind this types of error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did't set the options to use the CSS 3 profile instead of the default (CSS 2).

Answer (score 2):

Did you let the validator know you're using CSS3? I don't think media queries are part of the CSS2.* specification. This is the URL I use with my link: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer?profile=css3